# Importing a list of computers to Powershell to get OU

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do something I thought would be simple, but I've ended up hitting a wall...

I have a list of computers I've exported from a report that need attention, we organise our AD structure per geographic site and I want to run that list of computers through powershell to return the OU that they are located in.

I've put the computers into a plain csv, is there any simple way I can get an export of the OUs for just those specific computers?

For example, here is what I've got so far, but when I run it, it searches the first line of the csv always then the line? e.g it fails as it tries to search for "pc1.domain.com=pc7.cdomain.com"?

```
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\User\Desktop\Computers.csv 

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Get-ADComputer -Identity "$Computer"
}
```

Thanks
Matt

Update:

I've managed to get it to work the way I want now except exporting the CSV, it only exports the last result of the command?

```
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\User\Desktop\Computers.csv 

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $pc = $Computer.("ComputerName")
    Get-ADComputer -Identity "$pc" | Export-Csv C:\Users\User\ComputersResults.csv
}
```

Any idea what I need to do to capture all the results? When I run it without the Export the Powershell terminal displays them all...

Comment: Look at the Import-Csv and Get-AdComputer cmdlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be with how your CSV file organizes data. Make sure it is in this format or something similar.

[image]

You can have more columns to the right. When you import this csv file into powershell, it takes the row labelled 2 as the first element of a powershell Object. Then You can refer to `pc1.domain.com` by `row1.Name`. This would translate to ur code as:

```
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\User\Desktop\Computers.csv 

$result = ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $($Computer.Name)
    #To get the OU alone, you should do (Get-ADComputer -Identity $($Computer.Name)).DistinguishedName
}
$result | Export-Csv C:\Users\User\ComputersResults.csv -notypeInformation
```

Comment: That seems to work except there is something not quite right with the export, it's just giving me string lengths?

So the export looks like this:

#TYPE System.String
Length
89
89
91
79
76

Comment: Yeah, just have to add this: `-notypeInformation` to the export code

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar. I added a bit to the script, so you'll get the DN and hostname presented in the CSV file:

```
# Get OU from list of computernames

$Computers = Get-Content C:\Etienne\Hostnames.txt
$ExportPath = 'C:\Etienne\HostnameExport.csv'

$result = ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer | Select-object DistinguishedName,DNSHostName,Name
}

$result | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```